# Recursividad en C

Tags: c

sinceramente no entiendo porque no funciona este código, si alguien me puede dar una mano, tiene muy pocas lineas; **la consigna se trata de un vector, en donde la sucesión tiene que ser estrictamente creciente**, es decir, *un array: 3, 5, 7 -> cumple la condición; y un array: 5, 2, 4 -> NO cumple la condición*.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 50

typedef enum tBool{falso, verdadero} _tBool;

_tBool creciente(int v[TAM], int n, int i, _tBool fFlag);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    /* code */
    int vec[TAM];
    int i, n;
    _tBool c, mFlag;

    printf("Ingrese cantidad de elementos del vector: "); scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i= 0; i<n; i+=1){
        printf("Ingrese elemento %d: ", i); scanf("%d", &vec[i]);
    }

    c= creciente(vec, n, 0, mFlag);
    if(c) printf("La sucesion es creciente\n");
    else printf("La sucesion NO es creciente\n");

return 0;

}

_tBool creciente(int v[TAM], int n, int i, _tBool fFlag){
    if(i<n){
        if(v[i+1]>v[i]) return creciente(v, n, i+1, fFlag= verdadero);
        else return creciente(v, n, i+1, fFlag= falso);
    }else return fFlag;

}

/*
v, n= 3; el0= 2; el1=4; el3= 6;
creciente(v, 3, 0, fFlag)= creciente(v, 3, 1, verdadero); 
creciente(v, 3, 1, verdadero)= creciente(v, 3, 2, verdadero);
creciente(v, 3, 2, verdadero)= creciente(v, 3, 3, verdadero);
creciente(v, 3, 3, verdadero)= verdadero;
*/
```

Comment: Inclusive se podría optimizar el código en la pregunta if(v[i+1) > v[i] && fFlag) donde debería mandar fFlag como verdadero, y apenas sea falsa cortar las llamadas recursivas.. pero lo intente hacerlo de la manera mas sencilla posible pero no logre que funcione... agregaderia que alguien me tire algo de luz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef enum tBool{falso, verdadero} _tBool;
```

C dispone de un alias ya creado para tipos booleanos. Lo puedes encontrar  en la librería `stdbool.h`, que está disponible a partir del estándar C99, que data de 1999.

```
_tBool creciente(int v[TAM], int n, int i, _tBool fFlag){
    if(i<n){
        if(v[i+1]>v[i]) return creciente(v, n, i+1, fFlag= verdadero);
        else return creciente(v, n, i+1, fFlag= falso);
    }else return fFlag;
}
```

Vamos a analizar esta función por partes:

`if(v[i+1]>v[i])` si lo único que estás comprobando es `i<n`, ¿qué garantía tienes de que `i+1<n`? ninguna, luego vas a leer fuera de la memoria del arreglo.

```
return creciente(v, n, i+1, fFlag= falso);
```

Si ya sabes que no se va a cumplir la condición no hace falta que sigas recorriendo el arreglo... retorna un false directamente y ahórrate el resto del proceso.

Esta solución que aplicas tiene un problema adicional. Supón un vector tal que `1,2,1,2`. Al encontar el segundo `1` se llamará a `creciente(false)`. Esta llamada comprobará que `1<2` y llamará a `creciente(true)`... como hemos llegado al final del vector ese `true` es el que será devuelto finalmente lo cual es claramente incorrecto.

Así que, como has podido ver, lo mejor es no complicarse la vida. Si sabes que una condición no se va a cumplir no hace falta que sigas comprobando porque ya tienes la respuesta.

```
_tBool creciente(int v[TAM], int n, int i)
{
  if(i+1<n)
  {
    if(v[i+1]>v[i]) return creciente(v, n, i+1); // De momento se cumple...
    else return falso; // No se cumple la condición
  }
  else return verdadero; // Hemos llegado al final, luego el vector es creciente
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias... lo unico que no entendí es porque pones como condición (i+1<n), o sea mi idea era que es i comience en 0 y en algún momento iba a ser igual a n, (no contemple casos de números negativos porque la longitud del vector no podia ser negativa), o sea, porque no puedo poner i<n, si se que i es en principio menor que n, pero al ir incrementando estoy seguro que alguna vez va a llegar a valer n, y es ahi cuando quería que me de el resultado, incluso, realice la traza y no pude encontrarle el error al problema; sin embargo con la solución que planteaste funciona perfecto! Un saludo!

Comment: La función trabaja con `i` y con `i+1` por lo que tienes que asegurar que ambos índices son válidos. Si se da el caso que `i=n-1`, entonces `i+1==n`, por lo que al hacer `v[i+1]` estarías leyendo fuera del array.

Comment: Si se diese el caso de que no se deben admitir números negativos entonces la comparación tendría que ser `i>=0 && i+1<n`. Ya que `i` siempre va a ser menor que `i+1`, luego si `i>=0`, queda claro que `i+1>0`.

Comment: Entendi mejor... pero me parecía que contemplaba ese caso, porque ponía i<n, y no ponía y i<=n, o sea, en el momento en i valía n, ya no entraban las llamadas recursivas.. evidentemente estoy viendo algo mal...

Comment: Efectivamente, tu usabas `i<n`. Entonces `i=n-1` implica que `i+1=n` y, como te he comentado antes `v[i+1]=v[n]` y `v[n]` ya no pertenece al vector

Comment: Tenes toda la razón!! no lo podia ver, muchas gracias che!

Answer (score 1):

**Otra posible solución sería:**

```
t_bool creciente(int *v, int n){

     if(n == 0)
        return verdadero;
     if(v[n] >= v[n-1])
        return creciente(v, n - 1);
     else
        return falso;
}

esCreciente = creciente(v, n - 1);
```

**Explicando un poco:** 
La función recibe el vector y el tamaño, y lo recorre de mayor a menor. Si se encuentra en la primera posición es porque ya ha comparado todo los elementos, entonces es creciente; de lo contrario hay que comparar los elementos actuales  v[n] >= v[n-1]  , si es cierto esa condición se llama a la función con los siguientes elementos a comparar  creciente( v, n - 1) .
En caso de que no se cumpliera, ya no seria creciente y se retorna falso.

Comment: Sin desmerecer la respuesta de @eferion, tu código es como a mí me gusta: simple y práctico ... vamos, como debe ser. +1. De verdad que en los cursos o asignaturas de programación, parece que solo enseñan a complicarse la vida ...